# Linq select subquery

Tags: linq

As the title states, I'm trying to perform a select subquery in Linq-To-SQL. Here's my situation:

I have a database view which returns the following fields:

- SourceId
- LicenseId
- LicenseName
- CharacteristicId
- CharacteristicName

Now I want to be able to store this in a model of mine which has the following properties

- Id
- Name
- Characteristics (this is List which has Id, Name and Icon => Icon is byte[])

Here's the query I wrote which doesn't work:

```
var licensesWithCharacteristics =
                _vwAllLicensesWithAttributesAndSourceIdRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(x => x.SourceID == sourceId)
                .Select(a => new LicenseWithCharacteristicsModel()
                {
                    LicenseId = a.LicenseId,
                    LicenseName = a.LicenseName
                        ,CharacteristicList = _vwAllLicensesWithAttributesAndSourceIdRepository.GetAll()
                     .Where(x => x.LicenseId == a.LicenseId)
                     .Select(c => new CharacteristicModel { Id = c.CharacteristicID, Name = c.CharacteristicName, Icon = c.Icon })
                     .Distinct().ToList()
                })
                .Distinct().ToList();
```

How would you solve this? I'm trying to do this in one query to keep my performance up, but I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample query and models are not that coherent (where does `Icon` come from, Characteristics or CharacteristicList), but anyway.

I do this in two parts, you can of course regroup this in one query.
I enumerate the result after the grouping, you may try to do without enumerating (all in linq to sql, but not sure it will work).

```
var groupedResult = 
     _vwAllLicensesWithAttributesAndSourceIdRepository.GetAll()
         .Where(x => x.SourceID == sourceId)
         .GroupBy(m => new {m.LicenseId, m.LicenseName})
         .ToList();

var results = groupedResult.Select(group => new LicenseWithCharacteristicsModel {
                  LicenseId = group.Key.LicenseId,
                  LicenseName = group.Key.LicenseName,
                  Characteristics = group.Select(m=> new CharacteristicModel {
                       Id = m.CharacteristicId,
                       Name = m.CharacteristicName
                      }).ToList()
                  });
```

in "single query"

```
_vwAllLicensesWithAttributesAndSourceIdRepository.GetAll()
    .Where(x => x.SourceID == sourceId)
    .GroupBy(m => new {m.LicenseId, m.LicenseName})
    .Select(group =>
        new LicenseWithCharacteristicsModel
        {
            LicenseId = group.Key.LicenseId,
            LicenseName = group.Key.LicenseName,
            Characteristics = group.Select(m =>
                new CharacteristicModel
                {
                    Id = m.CharacteristicId,
                    Name = m.CharacteristicName
                }).ToList()
        });
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the Icon, I forgot to add that in my question. I added it a couple of minutes ago though and I'll try out your current solution.

Comment: Just to let you know, this works and I'd like to thank you for it. I didn't think about using GroupBy. If I don't get a single query answer, I'll mark this as the correct answer ;)

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens fine. I put the "single query" answer. If it doesn't work, just add a `ToList()` between the `GroupBy` and the following `Select`

Comment: @ThomasSchellekens and your day is not finished yet, now have fun ;)